# Building GMP 6.1.0 on 32 bit Windows 7 (MinGW): make fails on fib_table.c

Tags: gcc, mingw, gmp

I tried to build GMP 6.1.0 on my Windows 7 x32 PC (CPU is Athlon 64 x2). GMP is needed to build riscv-gcc.
I run configure as shown

```
     ./configure --prefix=/mingw --enable-cxx
```

it completes succesfully, then I try to make and after this command

```
     /bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -std=gnu99 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -I.. -DOPERATION_`echo fib_table | sed 's/_$//'`   -m32 -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -mtune=k8 -march=k8 -c -o fib_table.lo fib_table.c

     libtool: compile:  gcc -std=gnu99 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -I.. -DOPERATION_fib_table -m32 -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -mtune=k8 -march=k8 -c fib_table.c -o fib_table.o
```

I have an error

```
    In file included from ../gmp-impl.h:148:0,
             from fib_table.c:4:../mp_bases.h:4:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]

    Error, error, this data is for 64 bits
```

I have also tried

```
    ABI=32
     ./configure --prefix=/mingw --build=x86_64-w32-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w32-mingw32
```

but I still have the problem.

May be, anyone knows a solution?
Many thanks!

Comment: `on my Windows 7 x32 PC (CPU is Athlon 64 x2)` CPU is 64 bit but Windows is 32 bit? and what is the toolchain? 64 bit or 32 bit?

Comment: Yes, for some reason I use that configuration. Toolchain is 32-bit.

Comment: Did you run `make distclean` or use a clean new directory for the second try? Which mingw do you have and in what kind of window did you type this? What triplet did configure guess on your first try? https://gmplib.org/manual/Reporting-Bugs.html can give ideas of useful things to post even if you are not reporting a bug to that mailing list. I don't know if riscv-gcc has a special build procedure, but when building gcc, you can let it build gmp itself (see the gcc build instructions).

Comment: `x86_64-*` seems strange. If you want 32 bits, you should probably use `i686-*` instead.

Comment: @Marc Glisse, I use 'make clean' before each new try. MinGW is the latest one from here [link](http://www.mingw.org).

Comment: As for riscv-gcc, I try to build it, but get an error message about GMP absence. Then I've downloaded GMP and try to build it in separete folder and I got the described result. I did not find any info about this bug in [link](https://gmplib.org/) and if all my attempts will be faulty, I'll report a bug.

Comment: `make clean` is not sufficient if you change options. `distclean` is necessary (or get a new, clean directory).

Comment: @Marc Glisse, I've just used `make distclean` and then `./configure --prefix=/mingw --build=i686-w32-mingw32 --host=i686-w32-mingw32`. Unfortunately, result is the same((

Comment: If you do not need the latest GMP version, there is a solution like this `mingw-get install mingw32-gmp`. It works and I do not receive error message about GMP during riscv-gcc build. There are some other problems, but it is a separate topic)